# Spring-Rest controller не видит UserRepository

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, jpa, repository

Подскажите пожалуйста. Не понимаю в чем проблема, делаю всё по уроку, но ловлю такую ошибку:

```
Description:

Field userRepository in com.test.api.controller.TestController required a bean of type 'com.test.api.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.api.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Application file:

```
package com.test.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Model:

```
package com.test.api.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String login;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    @NotBlank
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.test.api.controller;

import com.test.api.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.test.api.models.User;
import com.test.api.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    // Get All Notes
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getAllNotes() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.test.api.repository;

import com.test.api.models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
# MySQL properties
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 1234

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Сборщик проекта - gradle.

Comment: Перед классом `ApiApplication` напишите аннотацию `@ComponentScan` и как параметр укажите основной пакет. По основным имею в виду тот в котором лежат классы распреледенные по пакетам. К примеру `com.example`

Answer (score 0):

[Включить надо](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.java-config)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.api.repository")
public class ApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло от части. Сейчпсй вылезла такая ошибка:
Description:
Field userRepository in com.test.api.controller.TestController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Comment: В Spring Boot такая ошибка обычно обозначает, что в зависимости не добавлены нужные библиотеки. Но это уже другая проблема, для которой нужен отдельный вопрос.